# Django filter json object's list by comparing with another list

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, orm

I have a model that has a field which is a JSON field. This json_field has a value which is a list. The database used is Postgres

```
model: 
  attr1:
  attr2:
  attr3:
  json_field: {
      jattr1:
      jattr2:
      array_field: [values ...]
  }
```

I have a queryset obtained from some other filter operation: `queryset`

I want to apply `model.objects.filter()` such that I obtain every instance where array_field values are present in the queryset.

For example: consider 4 instances

```
instance1: 
  json_field: {
      array_field: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }

instance2: 
  json_field: {
      array_field: [2, 4]
  }

instance3: 
  json_field: {
      array_field: [1, 4]
  }

instance4: 
  json_field: {
      array_field: [3]
  }
```

and `queryset` is :

```
queryset: [2, 3]
```

I am expecting something like this:

```
Model.objects.filter(json_field__array_field__in=queryset)

# This should return
instance1: 
  json_field: {
      array_field: [1, 2, 3, 4]
  }

instance2: 
  json_field: {
      array_field: [2, 4]
  }

instance4: 
  json_field: {
      array_field: [3]
  }
```

Right now this does not work as expected. And the last resort I have is to manually iterate through everything and create a filtered set of data which is not ideal at all.

Thank you for taking the time to read through the question and for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington I am using postgres

Answer (score 1):

the trick was to use `__contains` instead of `__in` so

```
Model.objects.filter(json_field__array_field__contains=queryset)
```

The above query does the job